# Insert char into char array C (string)

Tags: c

I got the char array "anana" and I am trying to get a "B" into the beginning in the char array so it spells "Banana" but I cannot wrap my head around how to construct a simple while loop to insert the B and then move every letter one step to the right

Comment: Copy it to another array.

Comment: Can you use a temporary array? Or does it have to be done in-place using the original array?

Comment: Wow I cannot believe I didn't come up with that earlier! Thanks

Comment: I will copy it to another array and then write every letter the same but one step to the right

Comment: If you're stuck doing it in-place, move the "anana" over by copying from right-to-left (or just use memmove(), which does that for you).

Comment: Show Your Code!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming:

```
char array[7] = "anana";
```

Then:

```
memmove(array+1, array, 6);
array[0] = 'B';
```

The `memmove` function is specifically for cases where the data movement involves an overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more traditional approach using...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char s[] = "ananas";
  char b[7] = "B";

  for(int i = 0; i < 7; ) {
    char temp = s[i++];
    b[i] = temp;
  }

  printf("%s", b);    

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why can I not start from the end of the string and loop backwards making the last character take the value of the previous one and avoid using another array. I tried but the changes wouldn't reflect. Please take a moment to look through [my code](https://codeshare.io/bug_rishav)

Comment: You can't dynamically resize an array in C since the memory has to be contiguous. Hence the reason for two arrays in the above answer. As for your code I recommend you ask a specific question on SO.

Comment: Okay what if i dont care about the last character and just want to shift the remaining characters to the right and add a new character in the beginning. Then am I allowed to do it? Coz im not resizing the array but just altering the array's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. Create a new array of size 7 (Banana + terminator). You may do this dynamically by finding the size of the input string using `strlen()`.
2. Place your desired character say 'B' at `newArray[0]`.
3. Loop over `i=1 -> 7`
4. Copy values as `newArray[i] = oldArray[i-1];`

Comment: Don't forget the terminator character! The string `"Banana"` is *seven* characters including it.